# ng-change using previous value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following input

```
<input style="margin-left:24px;" id="numOfRows" class="setupInput" size="10"
    ng-model="rowVal" ng-init="rowVal = gameCtrl.getNumOfRows()" ng-change="gameCtrl.setNumOfRows({{rowVal}})">
```

The issue I'm running into is when I change the value in the box it's always 1 behind.

EX: current value = 6

- Changed value to 3 - nothing happens
- Changed value to 2 - {{gameCtrl.getNumOfRows()}} returns 3

Why is it lagging 1 update behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have couple of issues here:

1) Do not use interpolation (`{{}}`) in the ng-change expression.
i.e Change

```
ng-change="gameCtrl.setNumOfRows({{rowVal}})"
```

to

```
ng-change="gameCtrl.setNumOfRows(rowVal)"
```

2) Do not use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for initialization, that is what controller is for, use your controller to initialize the value of `rowVal`.

3) Make sure you do not have old version of angular which had issues with ng-change/ng-model syncronization.

4) Assuming you are using controller As syntax (and previous statement is wrong) always try to bind properties to the controller instance, i.e use `gameCtrl.rowVal`. (It could be wrong because it is not clear from the context of the question whether it really should belong to the controller instance or is it inside ng-repeat or something the created the child scope).

Comment: If none of these then please replicate the issue in a demo.

Comment: The interpolation was the issue.